# Nox emulator with Rad Studio 10.2

Tags: delphi

I am getting "Unfortunately Project1 has stopped" error when I try to start empty FireMonkey application on Nox emulator. How to configure it to work with Delphi ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nox emulator can't work with Delphi Android apps.  Nox runs only on systems with Intel processors, but Delphi produces Android apps that run only on ARM processors.

Comment: Note that this is only because Delphi produces "native" apps that run under Java's NDK directly on ARM CPUs, they are not ordinary Java apps like most Android apps are. Many Intel-based mobile devices have Houdini installed, which runs ARM code on Intel CPUs. But only a few emulators can run ARM code on Intel CPUs (like BlueStacks and Genymotion), but Nox is not one of them.

Comment: Incorrect. I worked with NOX when I was on Berlin (NOX uses ARM emulator). Yes it worked with Delphi Android apps. Now I do not know what now because now I'm working with device directly.

Comment: This is wrong, I had the same thing happened after upgrading Delphi from v10.2.2 to v10.2.3. Setting NOX to use Android 5.1.1 solved the problem, here's how you do it : https://www.reddit.com/r/noxappplayer/comments/7dvhac/how_to_update_to_511_android_on_nox_60/dq4vrou/

Answer (score 2):

update your nox player to android 5.1.1 lollipop, or just add a new device and choose android 5.1.1
i'm always use nox player with delphi berlin without any problems